# Custom self-quoting forms: Useful?

Tags: lisp, elisp

Lisps often declare, that certain types are self-evaluating. E.g. in emacs-lisp numbers, "strings", :keyword-symbols and some more evaluate to themselves.

Or, more specifically: Evaluating the form and evaluating the result again gives the same result.

It is also possible to create custom self-evaluating forms, e.g.

```
(defun my-list (&rest args) 
  (cons 'my-list (mapcar (lambda (e) (list 'quote e)) args)))

(my-list (+ 1 1) 'hello)
  => (my-list '2 'hello)

(eval (my-list (+ 1 1) 'hello))
  => (my-list '2 'hello)
```

Are there any practical uses for defining such forms or is this more of an esoteric concept?

I thought of creating "custom-types" as self-evaluating forms, where the evaluation may for instance perform type-checks on the arguments. When trying to use such types in my code, I usually found it inconvenient compared to simply working e.g. with plists though.

***edit*** I checked again, and it seems I mixed up "self-evaluating" and "self-quoting". [In emacs lisp the later term was applied to the `lambda` form](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html), at least in contexts without lexical binding. Note that the lambda form does never evaluate to itself (`eq`), even if the result is `equal`.

```
(setq form '(lambda () 1))              ;; => (lambda () 1)
(equal form (eval form))                ;; => t
(equal (eval form) (eval (eval form)))  ;; => t
(eq form (eval form))                   ;; => nil
(eq (eval form) (eval (eval form)))     ;; => nil
```

As Joshua put it in his answer: Fixed-points of the `eval` function (with respect to `equal`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you presented doesn't define a type of self-evaluating form.  A self evaluating form that eval would return when passed as an argument.  Let's take a closer look. First, there's a function that takes some arguments and returns a new list:

```
(defun my-list (&rest args) 
  (cons 'my-list (mapcar (lambda (e) (list 'quote e)) args)))
```

The new list has the symbol **my-list** as the first elements.  The remaining elements are two-element lists containing the symbol **quote** and the elements passed to the function:

```
(my-list (+ 1 1) 'hello)
;=> (my-list '2 'hello)
```

Now, this does give you a [*fixed point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) for **eval** with regard to **equal**, since

```
(eval (my-list (+ 1 1) 'hello))
;=> (my-list '2 'hello)
```

and

```
(eval (eval (my-list (+ 1 1) 'hello)))
;=> (my-list '2 'hello)
```

It's also the case that self-evaluating forms are fixed points with respect to **equals**, but in Common Lisp, a self-evaluating form is one that is a fixed point for **eval** with respect to **eq** (or perhaps **eql**).

The point of the language specifying self-evaluating forms is really to define what the evaluator has to do with forms.  Conceptually **eval** would be defined something like this:

```
(defun self-evaluating-p (form)
  (or (numberp form)
      (stringp form)
      (and (listp form)
           (eql 2 (length form))
           (eq 'quote (first form)))
      ; ...
      ))

(defun eval (form)
  (cond
    ((self-evaluating-p form) form)
    ((symbolp form) (symbol-value-in-environment form))
    ;...
    ))
```

The point is not that a self-evaluating form is one that evaluates to an equivalent (for some equivalence relation) value, but rather one for which **eval** doesn't have to do any work.

### Compiler Macros

While there's generally not a whole lot of use for forms that evaluate to themselves (modulo some equivalence) relation, there is one very important place where something very similar is used Common Lisp:  [compiler macros](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bba.htm) (emphasis added):

> #### [3.2.2.1 Compiler Macros](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bba.htm)
>
> The function returned by compiler-macro-function is a function of two
>   arguments, called the expansion function. To expand a compiler macro,
>   the expansion function is invoked by calling the macroexpand hook with
>   the expansion function as its first argument, the entire compiler
>   macro form as its second argument, and the current compilation
>   environment (or with the current lexical environment, if the form is
>   being processed by something other than compile-file) as its third
>   argument. The macroexpand hook, in turn, calls the expansion function
>   with the form as its first argument and the environment as its second
>   argument. *The return value from the expansion function, which is
>   passed through by the macroexpand hook, might either be the same form,
>   or else a form that can, at the discretion of the code doing the
>   expansion, be used in place of the original form*.

> #### Macro [DEFINE-COMPILER-MACRO](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_define.htm#define-compiler-macro)
>
> - Unlike an ordinary macro, a compiler macro can decline to provide an expansion merely by returning a form that is the same as the original
>     (which can be obtained by using &whole).

As an example:

```
(defun exponent (base power)
  "Just like CL:EXPT, but with a longer name."
  (expt base power))

(define-compiler-macro exponent (&whole form base power)
  "A compiler macro that replaces `(exponent base 2)` forms
with a simple multiplication.  Other invocations are left the same."
  (if (eql power 2)
      (let ((b (gensym (string '#:base-))))
        `(let ((,b ,base))
           (* ,b ,b)))
      form))
```

Note that this isn't quite the same as a self-evaluating form, because the compiler is still going through the process of checking whether a form is a cons whose car has an associated compiler macro, and then calling that compiler macro function with the form.  But it's similar in that the form goes to *something* and the case where the *same* form comes back is important.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my misunderstanding of the term. It seems I mixed up *self-evaluating* and *self-quoting* (see extension of the question). Would you happen to know practical uses for the latter, i.e. for the fixed-point behaviour?

Comment: @kdb Yes, there's at least one important place:  compiler macros.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm just looking back at this now, and I think there's a bug in my self evaluating predicate.  A list beginning with quote shouldn't be self evaluating, it should evaluate to the second element of the list...

Answer (score 4):

What you describe and *self-evaluating forms* (not types!) is unrelated.

```
? (list (foo (+ 1 2)))
```

may evaluate to

```
-> (foo 3)
```

But that's running the function `foo` and it is returning some list with the symbol `foo` and its first argument value. Nothing more. You've written a function. But not a *custom self evaluating form*.

A *form* is some data meant to be evaluated. It needs to be valid Lisp code.

**About Evaluation of Forms**:

Evaluation of forms is a topic when you have source like this:

```
(defun foo ()
  (list #(1 2 3)))
```

What's with the above vector? Does `(foo)` return a list with the vector as its first element?

In Common Lisp such vector forms are self-evaluating. In some other Lisps it was different. In some older Lisp dialect one probably had to write the code below to make the *compiler* happy. It might even be different with an *interpreter*. (I've seen this loooong ago in some implementation of a variant of Standard Lisp).

```
(defun foo ()
  (list '#(1 2 3)))    ; a vector form quoted
```

Note the quote. Non-self evaluating forms had to be quoted. That's relatively easy to do. You have to look at the source code and make sure that such forms are quoted. But there is another problem which makes it more difficult. Such data objects could have been introduced by macros in the code. Thus one also had to make sure that all code generated by macros has all literal data quoted. Which makes it a real pain.

This was wrong in some other Lisp dialect (not in Common Lisp):

```
(defmacro foo (a)
  (list 'list a #(1 2 3)))
```

or even (note the added `quote`)

```
(defmacro foo (a)
  (list 'list a '#(1 2 3)))
```

Using

```
(foo 1)
```

would be the code `(list 1 #(1 2 3))`. But in these Lisps there would be a quote missing... so it was wrong there.

One had to write:

```
(defmacro foo (a)
  (list 'list a ''#(1 2 3)))  ; note the double quote
```

Thus

```
(foo 1)
```

would be the code `(list 1 '#(1 2 3))`. Which then works.

**To get rid of such problems, Lisp dialects like Common Lisp required that all forms other than symbols and conses are *self evaluating*.** See the CL standard: [Self-Evaluating Objects](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/03_abac.htm). This is also independent of using an interpreter or compiler.

Note that Common Lisp also provides no mechanism to change that.

What could be done with a custom mechanim? One could let data forms evaluate to something different. Or one could implement different evaluation schemes. But there is nothing like that in Common Lisp. Basically we've got symbols as variables, conses as special forms / functions / macros and the rest is self-evaluating. For anything different you would need to write a custom evaluator/compiler.

Comment: It seems that I mixed up *self-evaluating* and *self-quoting*, but it brought up some pretty interesting information it seems :)